# Start Method In Batch Not Returning Value

Tags: batch, class, query

Here is my start method of batch class at last line it is giving this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   Database.getQueryLocater(String)

```
global Database.QueryLocator Start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

        String Query='SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity';
        return Database.getQueryLocater(Query);
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: what are you trying to do? looks like you are trying to learn if yes check trailhead modules for learning https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch

Comment: I am trying to append a update word with opportunity name

Comment: @Saurabh Please edit the post and add the whole code.

Comment: Have you written Database.getQueryLocater(String) above the method? please put up your full code here

Comment: You mean you have a compile error not a method that is failing to return a value? As others suggests, cut and paste the entire class into your question; nothing appears wrong in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 2):

Spellcheck :) 
Database.getQueryLocator

Thanks
KL

Answer (score 0):

Best guess here is that you have your own class called `Database` (or `database`) or a field in your batchable class of that name that is shadowing (hiding) the system class. You can check that by adding the `System` namespace like this:

```
global System.Database.QueryLocator Start(System.Database.BatchableContext BC){
    String Query='SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity';
    return System.Database.getQueryLocater(Query);
}
```

If that fixes the problem, the best solution is to change that class or field name to avoid the problem so you don't have to keep adding the `System` namespace.

Comment: Keith -- overthinking this one :-) - OP misspelled method in code `Database.getQueryLocater(String)`

Comment: @cropredy Occam's razor in action...

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

global class batchaccount implements database.batchable{

```
global database.querylocator start(Database.batchablecontext bx){

    string query = 'SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity';
    return Database.getquerylocator(query);

}

global void execute(Database.batchablecontext bx,list<Opportunity> scope){

    for(Opportunitya:scope){
       //your code
    }
}

global void finish(Database.batchablecontext bx){

}
```

}